# How to set up Eclipse project for SAP Business Objects Java SDK

Tags: java, eclipse, sdk, business-objects

We have SAP BO 4.2 installed in house, and I've been told that REST is not turned on. I've written several successful .NET apps using the SDK to connect to and run against our production SAP box, and now I'm trying to write a Java app to do the same, as the Java SDK exposes more (and required) functionality.

I can't seem to get my Eclipse/Java/project environment set up properly to even start coding.

- Windows 10, 64-bit
- Eclipse version: 2019-03 (4.11.0)
- Java version:

  - openjdk version "12.0.2" 2019-07-16
  - OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 12.0.2+10)
  - OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 12.0.2+10, mixed mode, sharing)

I created a new "Java EE" -> "Application Client Project".

I'm not able to get the following code to "Run As Application":

```
import com.crystaldecisions.sdk.framework.CrystalEnterprise;
import com.crystaldecisions.sdk.exception.SDKException;
import com.crystaldecisions.sdk.framework.IEnterpriseSession;

public class Main {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        IEnterpriseSession oEnterpriseSession = null;

        String username = "username";
        String password = "password";
        String cmsname = "server";
        String authenticationType = "secEnterprise";

        try {
            oEnterpriseSession = CrystalEnterprise.getSessionMgr().logon(username, password, cmsname, authenticationType);

            if (oEnterpriseSession == null) {
                System.out.print("login failed");
            }
        } catch (SDKException sdkEx) {
            System.out.print(sdkEx);
        }

        //do processing here
        
    }

    public Main() {
        super();

    }

}
```

I have the following libraries referenced in the build path:

```
C:/Program Files (x86)/SAP BusinessObjects/SAP BusinessObjects Enterprise XI 4.0/java/lib/cecore.jar
C:/Program Files (x86)/SAP BusinessObjects/SAP BusinessObjects Enterprise XI 4.0/java/lib/cesession.jar
C:/Program Files (x86)/SAP BusinessObjects/SAP BusinessObjects Enterprise XI 4.0/java/lib/celib.jar
C:/Program Files (x86)/SAP BusinessObjects/SAP BusinessObjects Enterprise XI 4.0/java/lib/logging.jar
C:/Program Files (x86)/SAP BusinessObjects/SAP BusinessObjects Enterprise XI 4.0/java/lib/aspectjrt.jar
C:/Program Files (x86)/SAP BusinessObjects/SAP BusinessObjects Enterprise XI 4.0/java/lib/ceaspect.jar
C:/Program Files (x86)/SAP BusinessObjects/SAP BusinessObjects Enterprise XI 4.0/java/lib/TraceLog.jar
C:/Program Files (x86)/SAP BusinessObjects/SAP BusinessObjects Enterprise XI 4.0/java/lib/corbaidl.jar
C:/Program Files (x86)/SAP BusinessObjects/SAP BusinessObjects Enterprise XI 4.0/java/lib/ebus405.jar
```

Everything I've searched online for has fallen into three categories:

1. links to pages on SAP's site that no longer work (so redirected to general search page), or
2. outdated information/code, such that I'm not able to do the same, or
3. code that should work, once I get local environment set up and working properly

Additionally, all samples I've been able to find are for Java Server Pages, which is not what I want with this project.

When I try to run the above code, the error message I receive, even before it tries to connect, is:

> ```
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/omg/CORBA/portable/IDLEntity
>     at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
>     at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1016)
>     at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:151)
>     at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:802)
>     at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:700)
>     at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:623)
>     at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
>     at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
>     at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
>     at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
>     at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1016)
>     at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:151)
>     at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:802)
>     at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:700)
>     at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:623)
>     at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
>     at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
>     at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
>     at com.crystaldecisions.thirdparty.com.ooc.OBCORBA.ORB_impl.initializeDefaultPolicies(ORB_impl.java:369)
>     at com.crystaldecisions.thirdparty.com.ooc.OBCORBA.ORB_impl.initialize(ORB_impl.java:196)
>     at com.crystaldecisions.thirdparty.com.ooc.OBCORBA.ORB_impl.setParameters(ORB_impl.java:812)
>     at com.crystaldecisions.thirdparty.com.ooc.OBCORBA.ORB_impl.init(ORB_impl.java:1313)
>     at com.crystaldecisions.enterprise.ocaframework.idl.helper.ORBHelper.init(ORBHelper.java:57)
>     at com.crystaldecisions.enterprise.ocaframework.ServiceMgr.<init>(ServiceMgr.java:402)
>     at com.crystaldecisions.enterprise.ocaframework.ServiceMgrFactory.getServiceMgr(ServiceMgrFactory.java:66)
>     at com.crystaldecisions.sdk.occa.security.internal.LogonService.ensureServiceStub(LogonService.java:701)
>     at com.crystaldecisions.sdk.occa.security.internal.LogonService.doUserLogon(LogonService.java:885)
>     at com.crystaldecisions.sdk.occa.security.internal.LogonService.doUserLogon(LogonService.java:860)
>     at com.crystaldecisions.sdk.occa.security.internal.LogonService.userLogon(LogonService.java:240)
>     at com.crystaldecisions.sdk.occa.security.internal.SecurityMgr.userLogon(SecurityMgr.java:166)
>     at com.crystaldecisions.sdk.framework.internal.SessionMgr.logon_aroundBody0(SessionMgr.java:823)
>     at com.crystaldecisions.sdk.framework.internal.SessionMgr.logon_aroundBody1$advice(SessionMgr.java:523)
>     at com.crystaldecisions.sdk.framework.internal.SessionMgr.logon(SessionMgr.java:1)
>     at Main.main(Main.java:17)
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.omg.CORBA.portable.IDLEntity
>     at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:583)
>     at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
>     at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
>     ... 34 more
> ```

I understand that starting with Java 9, java.CORBA has been deprecated (and removed in Java 11).  I've tried changing the compiler compliance and facets to 1.8 with no change.  Additionally, the jar file "ebus405.jar" contains the CORBA classes.

Although I would appreciate help on getting past this error message, I would more appreciate it if someone can tell me a more straight-forward approach to getting this started.  I would embrace any of the following:

1. using a different IDE (I'm not tied to Eclipse)
2. referencing different/additional SDK Jars
3. tackling this from a different angle (e.g., different Java project type)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SAP definitely does not support Java 12, and in BW Modeling tools it is clearly stated that recommended JREs for Eclipse are 8 or 11, but not 12.

[image]

I do not know whether you use these tools but I suppose this dependency applies to others cases as well.

SAP explicitly is not saying this anywhere, but previously in all the documentation it was stated that only Oracle Java was supported, which was confirmed by multiple user experiences. I never have any problem with Oracle JDK but with OpenJDK had. So I recommend you to switch to Oracle 11 JDK.

As a last cast, as recommended [here](https://help.sap.com/doc/2e9cf4a457d84c7a81f33d8c3fdd9694/LATEST/en-US/inst_guide_abap_development_tools.pdf) (chapter 6.1.1), you can try SAP proprietary Java Virtual Machine, which is available on the Support Portal.

Comment: Thank you so much, @Suncatcher.  Late last night I used Java 1.8, and the error went away.  Oddly, I also had to switch to an earlier version of Eclipse as well, but that could be unrelated.  I poured over whatever documentation I could find to see what versions of Java were supported, but couldn't find any.

Comment: I was able to get it to work with AdoptOpenJDK 8.0.222.10.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are not using the correct JRE System Library. In case of doubt its always safe to use the one that comes with the BusinessObjects client installation.

I am using SAP BusinessObjects 4.1 SP6, so for me its located here - "C:\Program Files (x86)\SAP BusinessObjects\SAP BusinessObjects Enterprise XI 4.0\win32_x86\jre". Check the corresponding location against your version and set it as default for the project in Eclipse, then try again.

Comment: Thank you, @Goutam!  I didn't realize that there was a JRE in the SDK.  Although I got things working in Adopt OpenJDK8.0.222.10, I will also be investigating the JRE you point out.